# What is the integration of $\int_0^L e^{-bx^2} dx$

Tags: calculus

Is the integration of following functions possible??

$\int_0^L e^{-bx^2} dx$

Where L and b are constants.

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "possible". The integral is a [real-analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) of $L$, occurring widely enough to get its own name, erf (for [*error function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)), but it's well-known that erf is not an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). Loosely, "you can't evaluate the integral in closed form".